# CIFS connection to Windows 10 computer fails periodically

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

I am on a small network with an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and a Windows 10 computer.  Every morning on startup I connect Ubuntu to the Windows 10 computer with CIFS:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=[username],password="[password]",dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000 "//192.168.0.2/D Share" /mnt/smb_share
```

It usually works flawlessly, but once every several weeks this completely fails to connect.  Sometimes I can reconnect after running `nmap -Pn 192.168.0.2` but it doesn’t always work for me to reconnect.  Finally, I solve it by turning off both computers and the router, then turn  all three back on again.  That’s a primitive solution, so I would like a better way.

The router is both wired and wireless, but the computers are both connected by Ethernet cable, not WiFi.  The internet connection is always active on both computers whenever I try to connect, so it’s not a complete failure of network connectivity, only the CIFS connection fails.

Thanks very much for any better solutions to this CIFS connection problem.